# Does current flow if the current density $J=\sigma f=0$?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current

A current density $J$ is proportional to the force per unit charge and is of the form $J=\sigma f$. In cases of a conductor where $\sigma=\infty$ and hence $f=0$, is it that current is moving so slowly that $J$ can be approximated to be zero is it that all current in the conductor stops? How is this situation any different from when $\sigma=0$?

Comment: Why should $f=0$ when $\sigma$ is increased? This is Ohm's law, and what you call $f$ would be electric field (force per charge). The electric field (could be caused by a battery e.g.) is not altered because of high conductivity $\sigma$ of the wire material.

Comment: Are you basing your reasoning on mathematical indeterminate forms ? Or are you asking "if the current density $J$ is null, then is there no current density" ?

Comment: @Steeven I was incorrect to assume that $f=0$. So if $\sigma=\infty$, what does this say about the current density? That it too is infinite?

Comment: I think you should think more in reality than in math. It will make more sense for you. $\sigma$ is **conductivity** - That is, how well the wire lets charges move. That is, how easily it can conduct current. If a battery gives an electric field $f$ to a wire, this field starts to push charges. If the conductivity is *very large*, then it is *very easy* to move these charges. If you push a block over an ice surface, it feels like accelerating much faster, than if the surface was rough. Similarly, the charges will accelerate much more - that is, the current will be much greater.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ohm's law says ($\rho$ is resistivity, $E$ the electric field, and $J$ current density):

$$\rho = \frac{E}{J}$$

Your expression $J=\sigma f$ is the same thing, just with $f=E$ and conductivity $\sigma=1/\rho$.

Think of a battery connected to a circuit. The battery is the cause of any electric field $f$ that would start current flow $J$. The material of the wires and components of the circuit make up the conductivity $\sigma$.

- $\sigma \to \infty$ means you have an extremely well-conducting wire (a super-conductor) with close to no resistivity.
- $\sigma=0$ means the opposite: a very, very, very poorly conducting material (an insulator) with very high resistivity.

> In cases of a conductor where $σ=∞$ and hence $f=0$, is it that current is moving so slowly that $J$ can be approximated to be zero is it that all current in the conductor stops?

This seems to be a wrong assumption. The word `hence` shows me that you think it is obvious that electric field $f$ would be close to zero at a large $\sigma$. This makes no sense, and I think you are mixing up **conductivity** $\sigma$ with **resistivity** $\rho$.

If on the other hand you wish to keep a certain current density $J$ constant, then yes, for a very large $\sigma$ a much smaller $f$ is neede to cause the same current. This makes sense, since much better conductivity $\sigma$ logically means that much less force $f$ is required to move a charge and cause current flow $J$.

> How is this situation any different from when $σ=0$?

$σ=0$ means bad conductivity (and high resistivity against any current). For $σ=0$ no current will flow at all. This is an insulator, like plastic, that will not move charges.

Comment: So what does it mean for the current density when $sigma$ approaches infinity?

Comment: @OscarFlores It means that current density also reaches infinity.